# Nginx redirect to an external URL

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is route all requests to `/rdr/extern_url` to redirect to `extern_url` through my web server instead of doing it through PHP.

```
location /rdr {
    rewrite ^/rdr/(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```

What's wrong here is it if I access `http://localhost/rdr/http://google.com` my browser is telling me:

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

How do I redirect properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trivial check:

```
$ curl -si 'http://localhost/rdr/http://www.google.com' | head -8
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 09:33:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http:/www.google.com
```

As you can see, there is only one slash after scheme in `Location`.

After adding the following directive to `server`:

```
merge_slashes off;
```

We'll get the correct reply:

```
$ curl -si 'http://localhost/rdr/http://www.google.com' | head -8
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 09:36:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.google.com
```

---

It becomes clear from the comments you may want to pass hostname without the schema to your redirecting service. To solve this problem you need to define two locations to process both cases separately:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  merge_slashes off;

  location /rdr {
    location /rdr/http:// {
      rewrite ^/rdr/(.*)$ $1 permanent;
    }
    rewrite ^/rdr/(.*)$ http://$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Here I've defined `/rdr/http://` as a sub-location of `/rdr` just to keep the redirector service in one block -- it's perfectly valid to create both locations at `server`-level.

Comment: I tried adding `merge_slashes off` on the server context but I still get a single slash (after restarting nginx). Nice idea of using curl btw, I only test them on my browser.

Comment: As you can see it worked in my setup seamlessly. I advise you to localize the problem. Take the fresh setup of the same Nginx version with the only `server` and see what happens. Inspect "error" log, turn on debug logging.

Comment: What if you don't have the `http://` at the beginning? `http://localhost/rdr/google.com`

Comment: If you don't have `http://` at the beginning, then it gonna be `301` and `Location: www.google.com`, which means, your browser will request `http://localhost/www.google.com`

(please do not remove your comments: it makes hard for readers to grasp the flow of discussion)

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to settle that problem?

Comment: One option is to create another location: `location /rdr/http { ... }`